# android gradle: maven remote repository transitive dependency

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I have encountered problem while trying to make own android library.
This library has dependencies located in remote maven repository, build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        name "Some maven remote dependency"
        url "https://remote.maven.url/"
    }
}

compile 'remote.groudid:remote.artifactid:remote.version'
```

I use maven-publish plugin to publish my library to local maven repository:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            setGroupId(groupId)
            setArtifactId(artifactId)
            setVersion(version)
            artifact(bundleRelease)

            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.compile.allDependencies.each {
                    if (it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified".equals(it.name)) && it.version != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem appears, when i try to implement this library in the application. Gradle tries to find all dependencies only in repositories, which are specified in the application, not in the library. Application build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

compile 'mylib.groupid:mylib.artifactid:mylib.version'
```

Gradle sync fires an error: Error:Failed to resolve: remote.groudid:remote.artifactid:remote.version

Problem can be solved by directly adding "Some maven remote dependency" in the application build.gradle repositories, but i'd like to find a way not to do it manually in every app, which will be using this library. Is there a way to somehow transite remote maven repositories through my maven local repo? I tried to modify library pom file by placing repositories tag

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <name>Some maven remote dependency</name>
    <url>https://remote.maven.url/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

, but that didn't help.